# Tracing Code in Java Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm beginner and I used Lucene to calculate precision in my program, but results arenot correct. I want to know if there is any way for tracing the code to know what exactly happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways in which you can do this. If you are using lucene stand alone, you could download the source for it and put it in Eclipse and run the project from eclipse and that way step through and debug it.

or

Download Lucene source and put it in an Eclipse project. Start [tomcat in remote debug mode](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing) and attach eclipse to the running instance. That way you should be able to set break-points where ever you want. This is called [JPDA](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html).

Comment: If Lucene continues to be problematic check out Solr. It uses the Lucene library but extends it. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html